# How I do edit the css for just the home page on Magento?

Tags: html, css, magento

When using a template purchased from another site, by default the home page looked nice and the other pages had headers that were slightly 'off.'  When I asked about repairing the pages, I was given some .css code that fixed the other pages, but now the home page is off (seems pretty obvious).

Here's the site: http://nyctodesign.com/gulfsales/index.php/

As you can see, the header is correct for every page but the home page.  I looked up how to edit the .css for just one page, and got a tutorial that suggested a new file, say 'home-page.css' with my correct code, and this snippet of code below in the custom design xml:

```
<reference name="head"><action method="addCss">
<stylesheet>../theme300/css/home-page.css</stylesheet>
<params>media="screen"</params></action></reference>
```

I tried this code, and there is no change in the webpage.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this article http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/08/detect-page-in-magento/

Comment: Does the rendered source have a link to `home-page.css`?

Comment: I figured it out - thanks for looking at it, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up fixing it by coding opposite CSS as the other file - it gave a margin of 31 pixels on the header, so when I included the new home-page.css file, I changed this line to 0 pixels instead.

The code used above worked, I just had the relative URL in there incorrectly - now it uses the code I provided ONLY on the home page, and overwrites the regular 31 pixel margin.